# Inheritance and template function c++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I was wondering if there are pattern/ways to inherit template functions ?
Template functions can not be virtual so if my base class has a template function and my derived class has the same, the function of the base class will always be called in the following example :

```
struct Base {
    Base() {}
    template < typename T >
    void do_something(T&  t) const {
        t << "Base" << std::endl ;
    }
    };

struct Foo : Base {
    Foo() : Base () {}
    template < typename T >
    void do_something(T&  t) const {
        t << "Foo" << std::endl ;
    }
};

struct Bar : Foo {
    Bar() : Foo() {}
    template < typename T >
    void do_something(T&  t) const {
        t << "Bar" << std::endl ;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Base *b = new Base() ;
    Base *f = new Foo() ;
    Base *ba = new Bar() ;

    b->do_something(std::cout) ;
    f->do_something(std::cout) ;
    ba->do_something(std::cout) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

So this program always print :

```
Base
Base
Base
```

Is there a way to make my program print :

```
Base
Foo
Bar
```

Actually the only way I found for doing that is to make a static_cast :

```
...
static_cast<Foo*>(f)->do_something(std::cout) ;
static_cast<Bar*>(ba)->do_something(std::cout) ;
...
```

Is there any pattern or elegant way to encapsulate the cast so that it will be unnoticeable from the function call ?
Thanks for your replies

Comment: You can always use the [non-virtual interface pattern](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface): call a virtual function *from inside* the member function template.

Comment: If you know the types at compile-time, you can use static polymorphism / the CRTP to call member functions of derived classes from base classes.

Comment: ok thanks I will take a look to this pattern

Comment: non-virtual interface pattern example: See aschepler's answer ;)

Comment: @dyp no I do not know the type, I'm parsing a file and build a collection of Base during execution, I need to call do_something on each object once the parsing is done :/

Comment: Note that all standard output stream classes (`ofstream`, `ostringstream` and the type of `std::cout`) inherit from `basic_ostream<..>`, so you could use the parameter type `std::ostream&` in this example for all kinds of streams (they're polymorphic internally).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can almost always do what you need by splitting the function into smaller parts, making each part templated if necessary, or virtual if necessary.  In this example, that's as simple as:

```
struct Base {
    Base() {}
    template < typename T >
    void do_something(T&  t) const {
        t << something_piece() << std::endl ;
    }
    virtual const char* something_piece() const {
        return "Base";
    }
};

struct Foo : Base {
    Foo() : Base () {}
    const char* something_piece() const {
        return "Foo";
    }
};

struct Bar : Foo {
    Bar() : Foo() {}
    const char* something_piece() const {
        return "Bar";
    }
};
```

It can get more complicated than that, but the idea is pretty powerful at combining compile-time and run-time differences.

Comment: thx, It looks pretty and I can foresee how complicated it will be to implement it in more complicated examples but I think it's a good starting point for my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the option to change the struct to a Template class rather than template methods?

If so:

```
Template<typename T>
struct Base
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething();
 };


Template<typename T>
struct Foo : Base<T>
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but template function can not be virtual

Comment: No I can't change to a template class for the base class, it needs to be store in an std::vector<Base>